# Why do colors not show up (control characters) when piping stdout/stderr on *nix systems?

Tags: stdout, stderr, control-characters

Why do colors not show up (control characters) when piping stdout/stderr on *nix systems?

When I do:

```
foo | bar
```

if `foo` writes color encoded strings (with control chars) to stdout, they won't show up in bar - is there a way to get them to show up?

Comment: They do show up. You must be more specific, I suspect that you are talking about specific commands - for example `ls` detects if it writes to terminal and only then highlights the output. Test for example `echo -e 'abc\e[31mdef\e[0mghi' | cat`.

Comment: yeah when I am using a terminal, sometimes the colors still don't show up...?

Comment: Do you see red color with the command I gave or not?

Comment: no I don't but I think that's a different issue

Comment: It turns out, from comments here and on Stack Overflow, that the real question was about a _specific_ program _that the questioner wrote_ whose message colourization library has a particular behaviour.

Comment: yeah, I didn't know if it was standard for unix systems to do this or if the library I was using was doing it - initially I was thinking the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do colors not show up (control characters) when piping stdout/stderr on *nix systems?

As commented by [jimij](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80886/jimmij), they do show up.

However, some programs (probably most programs outputting [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)s) are detecting that their output is not a tty by using [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) e.g. as `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`; and that is a good feature, because dealing with escapes in pipelines when you don't want them is a pain.

Several programs document a way to force that, e.g. [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) has `--color=always`

So read the documentation of the relevant commands.

Comment: yeah in my case, I control both foo and bar, and I want to figure out how to get the colors to show up

Comment: You read the documentation of both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood - I am authoring foo and bar

Comment: That should be a different question. Then show the code, perhaps as [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask it on StackOverflow.

Comment: yeah maybe the package that I use to do the string styling will not do the styling if it's connected in a pipe? dunno

Comment: Again, ask a *precise* question on SO about that, with an MCVE

Comment: yeah I will, I will link to it here

Comment: here is the question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741639/terminal-styling-control-chars-using-the-chalk-npm-module

Comment: what about this answer http://bit.ly/2g9EF5C